# Custom Hook argument not being read on React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-custom-hooks

So, I'm getting the following error when trying to submit a form on React that uses a custom hook:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'url')  at sendRequest (use-http.js:5:1)

Inside the form component, I have the following code (which is triggered by the form submission)

```js
  const enteredDateRef = useRef();
  const enteredClientRef = useRef();
  const enteredTaskRef = useRef();
  const enteredTimeRef = useRef();

  const renderNewTask = (data) => {
    const taskData = {
      id: data.name,
      date: data.enteredDate,
      client: data.enteredClient,
      task: data.enteredTask,
      time: data.enteredTime,
    };

    setTasks((tasks) => [taskData, ...tasks]);
  };

  const { sendRequest: postTask } = useHttp();

  const submitTaskHandler = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const newTaskData = {
      Date: enteredDateRef.current.value,
      Client: enteredClientRef.current.value,
      Task: enteredTaskRef.current.value,
      Time: enteredTimeRef.current.value,
    };

    postTask(
      {
        url: "https://myurl.com/myurl.json",
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(newTaskData),
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application.json" },
      },
      renderNewTask
    );
  };
```

And here is the custom hook:

```js
const useHttp = (requestConfig, applyData) => {
    
    const sendRequest = async () => {

    const response = await fetch(requestConfig.url, {
      method: requestConfig.method ? requestConfig.method : "GET",
      headers: requestConfig.headers ? requestConfig.headers : {},
      body: requestConfig.body ? JSON.stringify(requestConfig.body) : null,
    });

    const responseData = await response.json();

    applyData(responseData);
  };

  return { sendRequest };
};

export default useHttp;
```

The custom hook is for http requests and apparently the argument is not being read when running postTask in the end. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Since definition of `sendRequest` doesn't have any params and you aren't passing config to hook, `requestConfig` is `undefined` even if you pass it to `postTask`.

You have to remove params to `useHttp` hook and add these to `sendRequest` function inside hook as below

```
const useHttp = () => { 
    const sendRequest = async (requestConfig, applyData) => {
    const response = await fetch(requestConfig.url, {
      method: requestConfig.method ? requestConfig.method : "GET",
      headers: requestConfig.headers ? requestConfig.headers : {}
      body: requestConfig.body ? JSON.stringify(requestConfig.body) : null,
    });

    const responseData = await response.json();

    applyData(responseData);
  };

  return { sendRequest };
};
```

Comment: That did the trick. I was using useHttp directly for other requests I couldn't figure out why it wasn't working on this specific scenario. Thanks.